# Send array in an URL query variable to a server written in Go

Tags: sql, arrays, go, url, query-string

I need to send a HTTP request with query to a golang server that uses [gendry](https://github.com/didi/gendry/blob/master/builder/builder.go) SQL library. Unfortunately, I don't have exact info about how the server is implemented.

When it comes to a simple query, there is no problem with it:

```
/api/resource
/api/resource?where={"age >=": 18}
...
```

However, I need to use `limit` and `offset`. For this, there is a `_limit` property, which should be an array of 2 numbers (offset and limit). There is a part of the library's code:

```golang
if val, ok := where["_limit"]; ok {
    arr, ok := val.([]uint) // first is offset, second is limit. 
}
```

The question is, how can I send an array through URL query string, so it will work? I tried several ways, but each returned an error, eg:

```js
// [builder] the value of "_limit" must be of []uint type
/api/path?where={"_limit": [0, 10]}
```

Comment: What about `/api/path?where={"_limit": []uint{0, 10}}`? (Just a shot in the dark, though.)

Comment: @kostix That returned another error: `"invalid character 'u' after object key:value pair"
}`.

Comment: That's interesting: the code of that SQL builder does not contain the substring "after object key:value pair", so it should be coming from the parsing code of the server itself.  Looks like it converts the `[]` to a map. OK, so what if you try `{0, 10} and even just `0, 10`? Please note that we're basically guessing here because that SQL builder the server uses does not seem to have any support for parsing of URL query parameters of HTTP requests, so this must be done in the server's code, and that either has to be documented or you need its source code.

Comment: @kostix `{0, 10}` returns `"invalid character '0' looking for beginning of object key string"`. And yes, I am aware it's just guessing. Sorry for not providing necessary details about the server.

Answer (score 0):

In http, you can specify an array of parameters be repeating the parameter.

```
/api/path?limit=0&limit=10
```

Your server should see `limit["0","10"]`. You can verify this with a simple curl request pointed a postbin such as https://hookbin.com/

```
curl -X GET "https://hookb.in/<YOUR HOOKBIN ID GOES HERE>?limit=0&limit=10
```